# Launch QGIS GUI using batch file and Python 3 - Windows 10

Tags: qgis-3, python-3, gui, bat

Ultimately I'm attempting to launch the QGIS GUI and run a python script from a batch file. I've reviewed numerous instances referencing similar scenarios on this and other forums but for the life of me I can't get it to work.

My batch file code is:

```
@echo off

SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.4

call "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.4\bin\o4w_env.bat"
call "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.4\bin\qt5_env.bat"
call "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.4\bin\py3_env.bat"
@echo off
path %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin;%PATH%
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT:\=/%/apps/qgis
set GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8=YES
rem Set VSI cache to be used as buffer, see #6448
set VSI_CACHE=TRUE
set VSI_CACHE_SIZE=1000000
set QT_PLUGIN_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\qtplugins;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qt5\plugins
set PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python;%PYTHONPATH%

python C:\temp\test.py
pause
```

My python script is:

```
import sys
from qgis.core import *

# Initialize QGIS Application
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.4\apps\qgis", True)
app = QgsApplication([], True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()

# Add the path to Processing framework
sys.path.append('C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.4\apps\qgis\python\plugins')

# Import and initialize Processing framework
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
import processing

print('Hello QGIS!')
```

Currently this code fails with the following message:
[image]

If I remove the importing of the processing framework section of the py script then 'Hello QGIS!' is printed in the batch window but the GUI does not launch.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else that stumbles across this question, I managed to solve the issue using a batch file with the following code:

```
cd C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.4\bin

qgis --project "path to .qgz project file" --code "path to .py python code file"
```

The `qgis` bit in the second line needs to match whatever .bat file is run to open QGIS. For some users this was qgis-ltr. This launches QGIS and opens a saved project, then runs the python script.

And my python script needed to start with the following to execute properly:

```
from qgis.core import *
import qgis.utils
from qgis.utils import iface
```

Comment: Thanks, I needed to add
"from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor"
to this as well, and I'm guessing others may need to import other things too

Answer (score 2):

Add an example that is working. It is very similar to yours but look at the \ and / (double slash and backslash).

It is important that they're the same as in my example. If it isn't so and I remember correctly it will not work for you.

**test_processing.bat**

```
@ECHO OFF 

set OSGEO4W_ROOT=D:\OSGeo4W64

@echo off
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\o4w_env.bat"
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\qt5_env.bat"
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\py3_env.bat"

@echo off
path %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin;%PATH%
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT:\=/%/apps/qgis
set GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8=YES

set VSI_CACHE=TRUE
set VSI_CACHE_SIZE=1000000
set QT_PLUGIN_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\qtplugins;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qt5\plugins
set PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python;%PYTHONPATH%

cd /d %~dp0

python3 test.py

pause
```

**test.py**

```
import sys
import os
import logging

# Append the path where processing plugin can be found
sys.path.append('D:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\qgis\\python\\plugins')

from qgis.core import (
    QgsApplication,
    QgsProcessingFeedback,
    QgsVectorLayer,
    QgsProject
)

from qgis.core import QgsApplication

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath('D:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis', True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], True)
qgs.initQgis()

import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()

print("Finished importing")

processing.algorithmHelp("qgis:zonalstatistics")

QgsApplication.exitQgis()
```

Console result:

[image]

I hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks Fran, that seems to have fixed the loading processing problem although i do get several DepricationWarnings regarding invalid escape sequences. However the GUI still does not launch? does it launch for you?

Comment: This doesnt launch the interface, it allows you to use interface functionalities but such scripts do not "open" QGIS or open UI