# Launch QGIS using a batch file

Tags: qgis, python, bat

I am very new to QGIS and Python 3. I have QGIS 3.32.1 installed and Python 11.  I do not have the OSGEO4W version.  My QGIS sits in the Program files directory (C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.32.1).

This is my batch file and it gets me all the way to where it is running the python script.

```
@ECHO OFF 

rem set OSGEO4W_ROOT=D:\OSGeo4W64
set OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.32.1

@echo off
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\o4w_env.bat"
rem call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\qt5_env.bat"
rem call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\py3_env.bat"

@echo off
path %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin;%PATH%
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT:\=/%/apps/qgis
set GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8=YES

set VSI_CACHE=TRUE
set VSI_CACHE_SIZE=1000000
set QT_PLUGIN_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\qtplugins;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qt5\plugins
set PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python;%PYTHONPATH%

cd /d %~dp0

python3 test.py

pause
```

This is the Python script (yes I am trying a previous question posted in this forum)

```
import sys
import os
import logging

# Append the path where processing plugin can be found
sys.path.append('C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.32.1\apps\qgis\python\plugins')

from qgis.core import (
    QgsApplication,
    QgsProcessingFeedback,
    QgsVectorLayer,
    QgsProject
)

from qgis.core import QgsApplication

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath('C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.32.1\apps\qgis', True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], True)
qgs.initQgis()

import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()

print("Finished importing")

processing.algorithmHelp("qgis:zonalstatistics")

QgsApplication.exitQgis()
```

This is the error I am getting, but can't figure out how to correct it.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\RDITLLLJ\Desktop\test.py", line 21, in 
> import processing ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'processing' Press any key to continue . . .

What can I do?

Comment: Where is the error message? Edit your post so the sections that show code are properly formatted (use the tool { } from the editor).

Comment: And what are you trying to achieve with all this?

Comment: I  am trying to learn how to launch QGIS from a batch file, but my installation is different then the solutions that I have found.  I am assuming there is a way to do it using the with the application installed in C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.32.1.

Comment: An answer to that is [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/329944/launch-qgis-gui-using-batch-file-and-python-3-windows-10)